# tgt daemon not working properly

Tags: ubuntu, iscsi

```
bl_root@bL:~$ service tgt status
tgt start/running, process 1544

bl_root@bL:~$  tgtadm --lld iscsi --op show --mode target
tgtadm: failed to send request hdr to tgt daemon, Transport endpoint is not connected
```

The error code indicates the daemon is not running -- why?

Answer (score 4):

The daemon really is running. You will need to use `sudo` to gain enough privileges to communicate with it, though:

```
sudo tgtadm --lld iscsi --op show --mode target
```

Comment: It answered the question for me. Unfortunately the error message is misleading.

Answer (score -1):

Are you by chance running the daemon with a control-port (`-C *int*`)? I got this same error on these commands and realized I need to also specify the `-C *int*` option on the admin tools to get it to talk to the correct instance.

Comment: I added a little formatting to indicate that `-C *int*` is something to type as part of the command. You might add a description indicating whether `*int*` is literal or, as I'm guessing, it indicates an integer of some sort.

Comment: I'll also point out that this particular question appears to have been self-answered by the OP a few years ago (and only a couple weeks after they asked it). It's missing the check-mark to indicate an *accepted* answer, but it's worth noticing that the OP probably already solved their problem.